# How to sync my branch with develop branch in Git

Tags: git

I created a branch called *my-feature* branch on June 2, 2023 by cloning *develop* branch. while I am working on my branch *my-feature* branch other developer pushed some changes in *develop *branch on June 4, 2023. Now I want to get the latest code from develop branch to *my-feature*.

```
git checkout develop
git fetch
git checkout my-feature
git rebase develop
git push -f origin my-branch
```

It gives me

```
you are already up to date but the change in develop branch is not come to my-feature branch.
```

Can you tell me how to rebase *my-feature* branch with develop branch?

Comment: Not sure if this is a real issue or a mistake made when asking the question, but you're rebasing `my-feature` and then pushing `my-branch`, which was not modified in this process.

Comment: After `git fetch`, you should pull the content of the remote branch with `git pull`

Comment: It _looks like_ you should first update local `develop` before running the rebase: `git checkout develop; git pull; git checkout my-feature; git rebase develop`.... just in case, you could skip _local_ develop altogether by running a pull against the remote branch straight: `git checkout my-feature; git pull origin develop` or even `git checkout my-feature; git pull` if you set the **remote** `develop` branch as its upstream (instead of the _local_ `develop` branch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't rebase. Just merge `develop` into your branch to keep it up to date, and keep on working. Assuming you are still "on" `my-feature`:

```
git fetch
git merge origin/develop
```

It's a good idea to do this periodically for a feature branch that you are working on for a long time. Note that the merge commit will not have any effect on the list of changes that will appear in the pull request.

Comment: git merge origin/develop worked. Dont we need to use rebase? I often hear people that you should do rebase to get develop branch code.

Comment: You could have rebased, but you didn't. The correct commands for that, while on `my-feature`, would have been `git fetch; git rebase origin/develop`. But what you tried to do was not that. You should learn Git before thrashing around with it. And you should delete your local `develop` branch immediately, as you do not need it and it is obviously just confusing you.

Answer (score 1):

You never actually updated your local `develop` branch.  `git fetch` checks the state of the remote and updates what your repo understands as the latest of origin (`origin/develop`).  I imagine if you go back to `develop`, and run `git status` it will say that you are behind some number of commits.

If you had done `git pull` instead of `fetch`, then the rebase would brought the changes over.  (`git pull` is a combination of `git fetch` and `git merge origin/<branch name>` or `rebase` depending on your settings.)